# Ошибка Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Ob.hpp

```
#ifndef Ob_hpp
#define Ob_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

class Ob
{
public:
    Ob(void);
public:
    ~Ob(void);
    virtual void Show()=0;
};

#endif /* Ob_hpp */
```

PAIR.hp

```
#ifndef PAIR_hpp
#define PAIR_hpp

#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Ob.hpp"
using namespace std;

class PAIR : public Ob
{
public:
    PAIR(void);
public:
    virtual ~PAIR(void);
    void Show();
    PAIR(int, int);
    PAIR(const PAIR&);

    int get_first(){return first;}
    int get_second(){return second;}

    void set_first(int);
    void set_second(int);

    PAIR& operator=(const PAIR&);
    void operator>(const PAIR&);
    void operator<(const PAIR&);
    void operator==(const PAIR&);
    void operator!=(const PAIR&);

    friend istream& operator>>(istream&in, PAIR&c);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&out, const PAIR&c);
protected:
    int first;
    int second;
};
#endif /* PAIR_hpp */
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Ob::Ob()", referenced from:
      PAIR::PAIR() in PAIR.o
      PAIR::PAIR(int, int) in PAIR.o
      PAIR::PAIR(PAIR const&) in PAIR.o
  "Ob::~Ob()", referenced from:
      PAIR::~PAIR() in PAIR.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Выходят вот такие ошибки при компиляции, если оставить только Class PAIR, то есть "public Ob" убрать, то все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редактор связей не видит определение конструктора по умолчанию класса `Ob`.

Вы его объявили

```
class Ob
{
public:
    Ob(void);
    //...
```

но либо забыли определить, либо не подключили к проекту файл, где конструктор определяется.

Comment: Это абстрактный класс.

Comment: @AndreyOshev И что? Как будет создаваться объект производного класса, если он не в состоянии вызвать конструктор базового класса? В любом случае подобъект базового класса должен быть создан для объекта производного класса. А это означает, что конструктор базового класса (и в том числе деструктор) должен быть определен.

Comment: #ifndef FRACTION_hpp
#define FRACTION_hpp
#include "PAIR.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

class FRACTION : public PAIR
{
public:
    FRACTION(void);
public:
    ~FRACTION(void);
    void Show();
    FRACTION(int, double);
    FRACTION(const FRACTION&);
    
    FRACTION& operator=(const FRACTION&);
    
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&in, FRACTION&l);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&out, const FRACTION&l);
};
#endif /* FRACTION_hpp */


Но в этом случае же все нормально.

Comment: @AndreyOshev Я не понял, к чему вы это привели данный код. Редактор связей вам ясно сообщил, что он не может найти определение конструктора, который вы объявили в классе Ob, и который вызывается при создании объекта производного класса.

Comment: Тогда не подскажите как эту ситуацию исправить? Я не могу разобраться.

Comment: @AndreyOshev Раз вы объявили данный конструктор по умолчанию, который вызывается конструкторами производного класса PAIR, то вы должны определить его. Либо вообще удалите объявление этого конструктора, чтобы компилятор сам сгенерировал конструктор по умолчанию. Такая же проблема имеется для деструктора.

Comment: Все получилось, убрал объявление этого конструктора. Все работает.